# Stumped on how to add a row in sqlalchemy python and postgres

Tags: python, database, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a table defined as follows and can use this schema to read from a database and create missing tables. Stumped on how to add a row to the database:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, select, table, inspect, MetaData
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, LargeBinary, Text, \
                       ForeignKey, Table, Boolean, JSON
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, registry, relationship
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base     = declarative_base()
engine   = create_engine(STR_CONN) #, echo=True)
metadata = MetaData(engine)
Session  = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session  = Session()

@mapper_registry.mapped
@dataclass
class UsersTbl():
    __table__ = Table(
    "users",
    metadata,
    Column("email_address", String, primary_key=True),
    Column("saved_state", JSON),
    )

    email_address: str   = None
    saved_state: str     = None
    lookupcolumn: Column = __table__.columns['email_address']
```

...

```
metadata.create_all(engine)
```

creates missing tables if needed

...

```
sql = select(table.__table__).where(table.lookupcolumn == lookupkey)

with engine.connect() as conn:
    dbdata = conn.execute(sql).all()
```

returns a row as expected

but when I try to add a row as follows

```
entry = UsersTbl("blah@blah.com", "{}")
session.add(entry)
session.commit()
```

I get an error
"""ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable) invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "users"
LINE 1: ...T INTO users (email_address, saved_state) VALUES (users.emai...
^
HINT:  There is an entry for table "users", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.

[SQL: INSERT INTO users (email_address, saved_state) VALUES (users.email_address, %(saved_state)s) RETURNING users.email_address]
[parameters: {'saved_state': '"{}"'}]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/f405)"""

Frustratingly I can get the following to work with posting data but can't seem to get it to work automatically creating missing tables as above or retrieving data :(
Any help is appreciated!

```
class User2(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    email_address = Column("email_address", String, primary_key=True)
    saved_state = Column("saved_state", String)

    def __init__(self, email_address=None, saved_state=None):
        self.email_address = email_address
        self.saved_state = saved_state


entry = User2("blah@blah.com2", "{}")
session.add(entry)
session.commit()
```

Any help would really be appreciated

Comment: Note the actual query, which has `[...] VALUES (users.email_address, [...]`. So it inserts the email address into users *from* `users.email_address`. That, of course, will not work.

Comment: The reason for that seems to be that you have `ookupcolumn: Column = __table__.columns['email_address']` in your `class UsersTbl():`, and then in the `sql` part that is passed into the connection, you have `.where(table.lookupcolumn == lookupkey)`. I'm not 100% clear on the workings of SQLAlchemy, but I think this part results in the problem noted in my comment above: a query that inserts something into a table column, taken from that same table column.

Answer (score 0):

```
stmt = insert(Tables.UsersTbl).values(('spongebob2d', "Spongebob Squarepants"))
with engine.connect() as conn:
    result = conn.execute(stmt)
```

did the trick :)

Comment: Please add and explanation.

Comment: This answer was reviewed in the [Low Quality Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-low-quality). Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Code only answers are **not considered good answers**, and are likely to be downvoted and/or deleted because they are **less useful** to a community of learners. It's only obvious to you. Explain what it does, and how it's different / **better** than existing answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/32606446)